# Mean of elements in a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

Suppose I had a list of data.frames (of equal rows and columns)

```
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
dat2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
dat3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))

all.dat <- list(dat1=dat1, dat2=dat2, dat3=dat3)
```

How can I return a single data.frame that is the mean (or sum, etc.) for each element in the data.frames across the list (e.g., mean of first row and first column from lists 1, 2, 3 and so on)?  I have tried `lapply` and `ldply` in `plyr` but these return the statistic for each data.frame within the list.

Edit:  For some reason, this was retagged as homework. Not that it matters either way, but this is not a homework question. I just don't know why I can't get this to work. Thanks for any insight!

Edit2: For further clarification:
I can get the results using loops, but I was hoping that there were a way (a simpler and faster way because the data I am using has data.frames that are 12 rows by 100 columns and there is a list of 1000+ of these data frames).

```
z <- matrix(0, nrow(all.dat$dat1), ncol(all.dat$dat1))

for(l in 1:nrow(all.dat$dat1)){
   for(m in 1:ncol(all.dat$dat1)){
      z[l, m] <- mean(unlist(lapply(all.dat, `[`, i =l, j = m)))
   }
}
```

With a result of the means:

```
> z
        [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.64185488  0.06220447 -0.02153806  0.83567173  0.3978507
[2,] -0.27953054 -0.19567085  0.45718399 -0.02823715  0.4932950
[3,]  0.40506666  0.95157856  1.00017954  0.57434125 -0.5969884
[4,]  0.71972821 -0.29190645  0.16257478 -0.08897047  0.9703909
[5,] -0.05570302  0.62045662  0.93427522 -0.55295824  0.7064439
```

I was wondering if there was a less clunky and faster way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Those aren't means. Those are medians.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a one liner with `plyr`. You can replace `mean` with any other function that you want.

```
ans1 = aaply(laply(all.dat, as.matrix), c(2, 3), mean)
```

Comment: why c(2,3)? what does that mean?

Comment: It is a way to access an array ... it basically , transforms the data to a 3-dimensional array and then takes a column mean out of it... elegant ...kudos

Answer (score 12):

You would have an easier time changing the data structure, combining the three two dimensional matrices into a single 3 dimensional array (using the `abind` library).  Then the solution is more direct using `apply` and specifying the dimensions to average over.

EDIT:

When I answered the question, it was tagged `homework`, so I just gave an approach.  The original poster removed that tag, so I will take him/her at his/her word that it isn't.

```
library("abind")

all.matrix <- abind(all.dat, along=3)
apply(all.matrix, c(1,2), mean)
```

Comment: I was not aware of abind, I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I gave one answer that uses a completely different data structure to achieve the result.  This answer uses the data structure (list of data frames) given directly.  I think it is less elegant, but wanted to provide it anyway.

```
Reduce(`+`, all.dat) / length(all.dat)
```

The logic is to add the data frames together element by element (which `+` will do with data frames), then divide by the number of data frames.  Using `Reduce` is necessary since `+` can only take two arguments at a time (and addition is associative).

Comment: This was actually a strategy I initially tried but this only works if I was trying to get means or sums, but I also wanted to have the option of finding the median. I think changing the data structure is likely my best option.

Comment: I can't think of how to adapt this to median; median needs all the elements at once while mean can be built up two at a time.

Comment: This answer is better than http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651775/4907 when the list of data.frame's is very long.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, however it fails when there is a character column (for instance a key that is the same in each list).

Comment: @jzadra True, but the "mean" of a vector of character strings is not well defined anyway. In where they would just be labels, the `data.frame` could be subset to remove them and then add a set back in afterward.

Comment: The problem with this method is that if you have NA values somewhere, they'll count as zeroes instead of being excluded from the calculation. Big difference.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach using only `base` functions to change the structure of the object:

```
listVec <- lapply(all.dat, c, recursive=TRUE)
m <- do.call(cbind, listVec)
```

Now you can calculate the `mean` with `rowMeans` or the `median` with `apply`:

```
means <- rowMeans(m)
medians <- apply(m, 1, median)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would take a slightly different approach:

```
library(plyr)
tmp <- ldply(all.dat) # convert to df
tmp$counter <- 1:5 # 1:12 for your actual situation
ddply(tmp, .(counter), function(x) colMeans(x[2:ncol(x)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use nested `lapply()` calls?

This appears to give the correct result on my machine

```
mean.dat <- lapply(all.dat, function (x) lapply(x, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: With this code you get the mean of the columns of each data.frame. You obtain the same result with `lapply(all.dat, colMeans)`.